# How to change the data type of columns of a vector layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, data

Is it possible to change the data type and attributions of data in QGIS?
Almost all of the variables which contains numbers should be changed in all of my vectors.
In ArcGIS the data type is recognised as the right one...

I tried all of the options in the options of the layers, but couldn't find any solution...

Comment: Had the same issue. The easiert way is to create new column and cut and paste it to there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you need to create a new column with the right datatype and parse the data from the old column to the new column (guess your using shape files). A new column can be made with the table manager and the update with the field calculator.

Comment: yo, shape files.... Thanks for the really quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new column works. I would like to have a go at getting it in a python script to automate this for me though. Any thoughts on where to start?

Comment: You should ask this in a new question as it will attract more attention than posting a question in an answer to a question that's already been answered.

Comment: Have a look at Table Manager. https://github.com/borysiasty/tablemanager it essentially does this for renaming columns.

Comment: See Processing -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector table tools -> Refactor Fields.